# Will iPhone applications compiled using the 2.x SDK be removed from the App Store?

Tags: iphone

Apple now says that apps built against the iPhone OS 2.0 SDK will not be accepted for the App Store.  What happens to applications already on the store that have been built using the older SDKs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They will stay online. But if you update them, use the correct new tools.

At least there is no sign that they will be removed - at least as long as they still work nicely on the new OS versions.